# How to get draw overlays permission from a library of an application in marshmallow

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get permission for drawing overlays in marshmallow.

In marshmallow we must give run-time permission for drawing overlays and I have implemented. What issue I'm getting is once I have given the permission from my app next time if I check with following code, if(Settings.canDrawOverlays(getApplicationContext()) it returns false.

But in settings (Draw over other apps) my app is Checked. Here I have provided my code of **lib** activity.

```
    if(Settings.canDrawOverlays(getApplicationContext())&& Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Windows Overlay allowed" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
startService(new Intent(this, FABService.class));
                finish();
        }
        else{
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION), 1);
        }
```

and my **onActivityResult** is,

```
 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    /** check if received result code
     is equal our requested code for draw permission  */
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        // * if so check once again if we have permission /
        if (Settings.canDrawOverlays(getApplicationContext()) && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            // continue here - permission was granted
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Windows Overlay allowed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startService(new Intent(this, FABService.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

These code I have implemented in lib of that application. Any 1 can help me where I have went wrong.

Comment: The same code if I give it in application's activity, I'm able to achieve this permission and also if (Settings.canDrawOverlays(getApplicationContext()) returns true

Comment: I think the problem is with the context(in lib) which I'm using to get the permission, that's the reason I have used getApplicationContext() but even then in onActivityResult I'm unable to achieve

Answer (score 2):

Put permission in Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Use this for Overlay permission

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
    // Show alert dialog to the user saying a separate permission is needed
    // Launch the settings activity if the user prefers
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```